# how to execute dynamically created html code in string variable in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, runtime

I have some HTML code in a [String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) variable in C#.

That code generated and stored in [String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) variable at run-time. 
But now I want to execute this code at run time.
All I want to do is see how that code looks in BROWSER.

How can I do this?

Is there any control in asp.net that provides such functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use any contol like `panel` `literal`.

Suppose you have a string

```
string str="<p><div>Some Text</div></p>";
Literal1.Text = str;
```

### html

```
 <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

Comment: can u present some example please?

Comment: can u help in xslt?

about executing xslt in asp.net and some more.

Comment: Kindly mark it selected if it help your. And you should put a new question in SO for the same.

Answer (score 1):

in your .aspx put html tag (div, paragraph, label etc) with property    **runat=server**

```
     <p id="dynamicstring" runat="server"></p>
```

in codebehind

```
               dynamicstring.InnerText= yourstring;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringBuilder and then Simply use Response.Write for StringBuilder